# Android, ListView adapter

Tags: android-listview

I have some question regarding Android programming. More specific, I have a ListView where every single row is containg five widgets and each trigger event. I have created custom adapter and defined events handler for every widgets in the getView method. Everything works fine, however the code looks quite long, unreadable and nasty because of all these event handlers inside. Is there any better design? Maybe Creating event handlers outside the getView method or something else?
greetings

According to suggestion I posted part of the source code. As you can see I have created few event handlers outside the getView method and two inside. I really do not know which design is better.

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HourReport> {

private static Activity context;
private int resourcecId;
private TextView fromTime;
private TextView toTime;
private TextView total;
private HourReport rowModelBean;
private HourReport rowBean;
private CheckBox billable;
private ArrayList<HourReport> list;
private HourReportCatalog catalog;
private Map<Integer, Integer>selectedItems;
private Map<Integer, Integer>selectedRoles;




public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resourcecId,
        ArrayList<HourReport> list, HourReportCatalog catalog) {
    super(context, resourcecId, list);
    this.catalog = catalog;
    ListViewAdapter.context = context;
    this.resourcecId = resourcecId;
    this.list = list;
    selectedItems = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    selectedRoles = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

}


// event handler for delete button "-"

private OnClickListener delete = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View deletBtnF) {

        int myPosition = (Integer) deletBtnF.getTag();
        HourReport r = list.remove(myPosition);
        selectedItems.put(myPosition, 0);
        selectedRoles.put(myPosition, 0);
        r.setTimeFinished(null);
        r.setTimeStarted(null);
        r.setTaks(null);
        r.setTotal(0.0);
        r.setBillable(false);
        r.setEngagementContractID(0);       
        list.add(myPosition, r);  
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (r.getDateCreated() != null) {
            Log.e("Listview adapter", "inside the if statement");
            Long id = r.getHourReportID();
            Log.e("", "date created" + r.getDateCreated());
            catalog.deleteHourReport(r);
            r.setDateCreated(null);
        }
    }

};

// event handler for textView which is responsible for defining dateFrom
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
OnClickListener onClickLisOnDateFrom = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View editField) {

        Integer position1 = (Integer) editField.getTag();
        TableRow parent = (TableRow) editField.getParent();
        fromTime = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.viewTextFrom);
        total = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.textViewShowsTotal);
        rowBean = getModel(position1);

        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener1 = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                String time = hour + ":" + minutes;
                fromTime.setText(time);
                setTimeFieldFrom(time);
                String totalTime = totalHourCalculator();
                total.setText(totalTime);

            }
        };
        new TimePickerDialog(context, timeListener1,
                c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
                .show();

    }
};
// event handler for textView which is responsible for defining dateTo
private OnClickListener onClickLisOnDateTo = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View editField) {
        Integer position1 = (Integer) editField.getTag();
        Log.e("ListView - Timer ", "position: " + position1);
        TableRow parent = (TableRow) editField.getParent();
        toTime = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.viewTextFrom);
        total = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.textViewShowsTotal);
        rowBean = getModel(position1);

        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener2 = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                String time = hour + ":" + minutes;
                toTime.setText(time);
                setTimeFieldTo(time);
                String totalTime = totalHourCalculator();
                total.setText(totalTime);
            }
        };
        new TimePickerDialog(context, timeListener2,
                c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
                .show();
    }
};

        // event handler for check box
private OnClickListener checkBoxListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View checkBox) {

        Integer num = (Integer) checkBox.getTag();
        rowBean = getModel(num);
        if (rowBean.isBillable()) {
            rowBean.setBillable(false);
        } else {
            rowBean.setBillable(true);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    getHourReportList();
    TextView deleteBtnV = null;
    View row = convertView;
    Spinner taskSpinner, roleSpinner;
    TextView addReport;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(resourcecId, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);           
        fromTime = viewHolder.getFromTime();
        deleteBtnV = viewHolder.getDeleteBtnVView();
        deleteBtnV.setOnClickListener(delete);
        billable = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
        addReport = viewHolder.getAddButtonView();

        // event handler for the button "+" which adds extra row
        addReport.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override   
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Integer myPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
                HourReport report = list.get(myPosition);
                HourReport nReport = new HourReport();
                nReport.setClaimDate(report.getClaimDate());
                nReport.setEmployeeID(report.getEmployeeID());
                nReport.setBillable(false);
                nReport.setEngagementContractID(0);
                list.add(myPosition + 1, nReport);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        viewHolder.adapter = new SpinerAdapter(context);            
        taskSpinner = viewHolder.getSpinnerTask();
        roleSpinner = viewHolder.getSpinnerRole();

        //event handler for the spinner
        taskSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View spin,
                    int selected, long arg3) {
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) spin.getParent();
                Integer myPosition = (Integer) spinner.getTag();                    
                viewHolder.adapter.setSelected(selected);                   
                String task = viewHolder.adapter.getSelectcetdTask();
                long engmId = viewHolder.adapter.getSelectedTaskID();
                rowBean = getModel(myPosition);                   
                rowBean.setTaks(task);   
                rowBean.setEngagementContractID(engmId);
                selectedItems.put(myPosition, selected);                    
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {   
            }
        });

        ////event handler for the spinner
        roleSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View spin,
                    int selectedRole, long arg3) {                  
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) spin.getParent();
                Integer myPosition = (Integer) spinner.getTag();
                selectedRoles.put(myPosition, selectedRole);                
            }   

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }
        });

        fromTime = viewHolder.getFromTime();
        toTime = viewHolder.getToTime();
        fromTime.setOnClickListener(onClickLisOnDateFrom);
        toTime.setOnClickListener(onClickLisOnDateTo);
        billable.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        fromTime = viewHolder.getFromTime();
        toTime = viewHolder.getToTime();
        taskSpinner = viewHolder.getSpinnerTask();
        roleSpinner = viewHolder.getSpinnerRole();
        total = viewHolder.getTotal();
        billable = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
        TextView date = viewHolder.getDate();
        deleteBtnV = viewHolder.getDeleteBtnVView();
        addReport = viewHolder.getAddButtonView();

    }
    HourReport model = getModel(position);
    Integer selection = 0;
    if (selectedItems.get(position) != null) {
        selection = selectedItems.get(position);
    }
    int selectionR = 0;
    if (selectedRoles.get(position) != null) {
        selectionR = selectedRoles.get(position);
    }

    viewHolder.getFromTime().setText(
            parseDateToString(model.getTimeStarted()));
    viewHolder.getToTime().setText(
            parseDateToString(model.getTimeFinished()));
    viewHolder.getTotal().setText(
            convertDoubleTotToStringTot(model.getTotal()));
    viewHolder.getDate().setText(
            parseDateToStringDDate(model.getClaimDate()));
    viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(model.isBillable());

    Log.e("", "tag " + selection + " date " + model.getClaimDate());

    viewHolder.taskSpinner.setSelection(selection);
    viewHolder.roleSpinner.setSelection(selectionR);
    fromTime.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    toTime.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    taskSpinner.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    roleSpinner.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    billable.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    deleteBtnV.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    addReport.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));

    return row;
}![here you have screen shoot of single row][1]
```

Comment: I would recommend posting your code so that folks can have a better look at what they're trying to help you fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single instance of `OnClickListener` (for example as an inner class) and assign this instance to every widget. If you need to know which row this widget belongs to, you can call `setTag("pos", position)` on that widget. By doing this you will be able to get position by calling `view.getTag("pos")` in `onClick(View view)` method of the listener. Hope this helps.